# Android java conversion problem

Tags: java

I have currently the problem that I like to send some commands to an embedded devices via bluetooth (encoded in 16 bits). Unfortunately there seems to be a conversion error in Java or at least I don't know how to handle it.

These bits are e.g. 1001 0010 1011 0010 
I thought about using char for this (16bit), but sometimes it's converted by Java to 24 bits (3 printed characters), when I try to add it to a string. This depends on the integer value.

How can I get the printed ASCII (or whatever) characters here? The bluetooth-function requires a String as parameter.

```
        int a = 127, b = 221;  // 0-255  32 bit
            char p1 = (char) b; // 0000 0000 bbbb bbbb  16 bit
            char p2 = (char) a; // 0000 0000 aaaa aaaa  16 bit

            // bbbb bbbb aaaa aaaa
        char anUnsignedShort = (char) ((p1 << 8) | p2);  // 16 bit
        System.out.println(""+(char)2+anUnsignedShort+(char)3);
        // ???? ???? bbbb bbbb aaaa aaaa  -- 24bits sometimes. Why ???
```

Comment: Well, I found out that it's a real java problem by print (char) 137 to 139 ... how can I print 139 as 8bit character?
I/System.out( 6466): ┬ë
I/System.out( 6466): ┬è
I/System.out( 6466): ┬ï

Comment: I'm seeing http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/252c/index.htm followed by http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00eb/index.htm, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e8/index.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ef/index.htm, respectively. How do those relate to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to know about the implicit conversions of the [*String Concatenation Operator +*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.18.1). Alternatively, consider a `byte[]`, suitable for [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html):

```
byte[] ba = {(byte) 2, (byte) 221, (byte) 127, (byte) 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ba));
```

Addendum:

> I need it as `character` - in this case 4 bytes 0x02, *etc*.

The same principle would apply, except you'd be getting the platform's default character encoding.

```
char[] ca = {(char) 2, (char) 221, (char) 127, (char) 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ca));
```

Comment: The output of your code is [2, -35, 127, 3]  ... I need it as character - in this case 4 bytes 0x02, ...

Comment: @Nils: I've elaborated above. If it's relevant, you'll be getting the platform's default character encoding, rather than the device's.