# Convert INT(0-255) to UTF8 char in Java

Tags: java, integer

since I need to control some devices, I need to send some bytes to them. I'm creating those bytes by putting some int values together (and operator), creating a byte and finally attaching it to a String to send it over the radio function to the robot.

Unfortuantely Java has some major issues doing that (unsigned int problem)

Does anybody know, how I can convert an integer e.g.

```
x = 223;
```

to an 8-bit character in Java to attach it to a String ?

```
char = (char)x;   // does not work !! 16 bit !! I need 8 bit !
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android java conversion problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595373/android-java-conversion-problem)

Comment: Note that an UTF-8 character is **not** an 8-bit character. UTF-8 is a specific encoding for Unicode characters. A character can take up multiple bytes in UTF-8. In fact, this question doesn't have anything to do with UTF-8.

Comment: [this answer will help you get if not what you want but could give you a clue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385153/4617869)

Answer (score 1):

A `char` *is* 16-bit in Java. Use a `byte` if you need an 8-bit datatype.

See [*How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java) on how to convert a `byte[]` to `String` with UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a java.lang.String over the wire is probably the wrong approach here, since Strings are always 16-bit (since Java was designed for globalization and stuff). If your radio library allows you to pass a byte[] instead of a String, that will allow you to send 8-bit values without needing to worry about converting to UTF8. As far as converting from an int to an unsigned byte, you'll probably want to look at [this article](http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

int to array of bytes

```
public byte[] intToByteArray(int num){
      byte[] intBytes = new byte[4];
      intBytes[0] = (byte) (num >>> 24);
      intBytes[1] = (byte) (num >>> 16);
      intBytes[2] = (byte) (num >>> 8);
      intBytes[3] = (byte) num;
      return intBytes;
}
```

note endianness here is big endian.

Comment: This is 32 bits, though. The question says *"I need 8 bit"*