# NumberFormatException when parsing strings containing non-integers

Tags: java, integer

I get: `java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)`

when I try to use:

```
Integer.parseInt("h");
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt("h".toString());
```

but I was expecting it to work like `atoi` in c.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And what you expect to receive?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: you are trying to convert a `String` (not a number represent as a String, let say "1", but a letter) to an `int`. That's your mistake, but as already asked: what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: I need to convert text to ints like atoi in c.

Comment: `atoi` works almost the same as `Integer.parseInt`, except that instead of throwing an exception it reports an error through a `0` return value. Really, if that's what you're after, just catch the exception and return `0` yourself. Although that's a fairly dumb solution, as an exception is much more appropriate here.

Comment: as far i remember (but i'm not expert on math) 'h' is not a number.

Comment: Ahh. Then you need to wrap it in some kind of try catch. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486077/java-good-way-to-encapsulate-integer-parseint  Though I should add that I agree with Mattias...if you're passing in an unparsable string, that's a problem, and it should probably throw an exception, rather than just swallow it and return an arbitrary and potentially misleading value.

Answer (score 3):

The `String` literal "h" obviously does not represent a valid integer.

Assuming `h` is your `String` variable, you don't need to use quotes:

```
String h = "1234";
Integer.parseInt(h);
```

**Update:**
The function [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) returns an integer value of the input argument and returns zero if the input value is not valid. In Java, you could write this:

```
public static int javaAToI(String text) {
   try {
      return Integer.parseInt(text);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: This works if my string is a integer like in your example, but I need to convert text to int. for example string h = "h";

Comment: So what value would your "h" have?

Comment: Are you looking for the ascii value of "h" then?

Comment: `"h".charAt(0)` will be `'h'` - did you forget the cast to `int` ? ;)

Comment: @Reimeus yes ascii to int

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if you parse it a `String` that resembles `Integer`.

You are parsing it a literal `"h"` which can not be interpreted as Integer. If you parse it `"123"` it will work.

Documentation of your method can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and documentation is usually a good place to start your search.

As someont else also suggested- if `h` is your variable, parse it in this way: `Integer.parseInt(h);`.

**Edit:**

If you want to convert a `char` into `int`, here is your answer: [get char value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329275/get-char-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java is doing exactly what it is supposed to here.  In `atoi`, when you are returned a 0, how do you know if your string contained a 0, or if it had a string that was not parsable?  Java handles this by letting you know that you've tried to parse a string that doesn't contain a parsable value...ideally so you can go back and fix the code that is passing in an unparsable value.

In your case, if you wanted to handle the situation exactly like C does, you could just return a 0 if you catch a NumberFormatException.  (It would probably be better if you could go back and ensure that you're not passing in bad strings, but that's not always possible.)